# Push Notification not working in foreground IOS

Tags: objective-c, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

push notification is working perfectly fine when app is in background, the main issue arises when the app is in foreground. I am able to receive the payload but the notification is not shown in the notification banner

payload received below

```js
{"data": {"fcm_options": {"image": "https://importduniya.com/dealer/particular/TrustyCane.jpg"}}, "messageId": "1591459535622805", "mutableContent": true, "notification": {"body": "Test123", "ios": {}, "title": "Test"}, "sentTime": "1591459535"}
```

I think the below function is not getting called when the app is in foreground

```js
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@"will-present");
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** as well